# if statements inside a for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to understand how I can use if statements inside a for loop in Matlab.
I d like my Go[] array be like this [1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3] instead of the image's results [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3].

Could someone help me with the code?

```
for f=1:10
   if (f>=1)&&(f<=5)
      Go=1;
   end
   if  (f>5)&&(f<7)
      Go=2;     
   end 
   if (f>=7)
      Go=3; 
   end
   F(f)=f;
   Go(f)=Go;
end
plot(F,Go)
```

[My results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjsxo.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Suggested Solution**

A better approach to solve this problem will be as follows:

```
Go = [ones(1,5),2,ones(1,4)*3];
F = 1:10;
```

**Issues with your solution**

I strongly recommend to fully understand my suggested code above, and use it.
However, for learning purposes, if we do want to make your code work, there are two main issues two be handled:

1. The best use-case is to define Go and F before the loop start as empty vectors.
2. during the run of the loop, use a different variables (other then Go) to hold the temporary values to be assigned.

code example:

```
Go = zeros(1,10);
F = zeros(1,10);
for f=1:10
   if (f>=1)&&(f<=5)
      temp=1;
   elseif  (f>5)&&(f<7)
      temp=2;    
   else
      temp=3; 
   end
   F(f)=f;
   Go(f)=temp;
end
plot(F,Go)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've written in your question you are overwriting the value of Go on each iteration of the loop!

So in the last iteration, the if statement sets `Go=3` (i.e. a scalar or matrix of size 1x1), then the assignment sets `Go(10) = 3` (size = 1x10) and all the values in between (i.e. `2:9`) are 0s because they have not been initialised.

You basically have a logical error in your code.

Comment: can u help with the code in order to understand what do u mean. Why F[] is working as I want is my logic is wrong?

Comment: MATLAB doesn't index that way. Please don't answer questions if you don't understand the basic syntax of the language yourself.

Comment: @Adriaan Is it just the backets of `Go[10]` bothering you? Yes it should be parenthesis, but the whole explanation remains correct.

Comment: @kosar Remove the semicolons from the lines where `Go` is used, and you will see this evolution;

Comment: @Adriaan - My answer was to point out that the problem was a logical error and I hoped to give enough info to help the poster find the solution his/herself. Apologies for the slopiness.